# Passing arrays as URL parameter with combinations

Tags: php, arrays

I'm kinda stucked here.
I'm trying to build URL for product variants like:

```
&brand=6&color=11,12,etc
```

So how can I combine the keys of array into one string like above

Also If you could suggest me another way to achieve the desired result.
Thank you very much!

Comment: can you explain the logic ?

Comment: Also, can you please edit the question, and show your input array in the form [`var_export`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) returns. That way, people can easily copy&paste it to have the basis for creating a working test example.

Comment: I'll edit in a moment to be more specific

Comment: Guys, i just edited my post with a pic. It's good now? Do you understand what I meant?

Comment: how do you decide the color and branch allotment since both the array sizes are different.

Comment: I'll edit with my full code. Just a sec

Comment: @Suchit kumar, full code in my post.

Comment: @CBroe can u check the code now ?

Comment: I still don't see a proper explanation of what you want to achieve. Stop painting arrows on images, and start using your words to describe what your problem is.

Comment: Create a php file with the code and execute it with some parameters like localhost/&brand=1,2&color=1

Answer (score 0):

You first have to combine the values of "brand" with the values of "color". Afterwards, you can output them together:

```
<?php

$columns = [
    'brand' => [
        ['b1A', 'b1B'],
        ['b2A', 'b2B'],
    ],
    'color' => [
        ['c1A', 'c1B'],
        ['c2A', 'c2B'],
    ],
];

$data = [];
foreach ($columns as $title => $rows) {
    foreach ($rows as $id => $values) {
        if (!isset($data[$id])) {
            $data[$id] = [];
        }

        $data[$id][$title] = $values;
    }
}

foreach ($data as $row) {
    $output = '';
    foreach ($row as $key => $values) {
        $output .= '&' . $key . '=' . implode(',', $values);
    }

    echo $output . '<br/>' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Hello @ckappelhoff, thanks for your answer. Can you check my post, I just edited with my full code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$filters = [
    "brand" => [
        1 => "Adidas",
        2 => "Puma"
    ],
    "color" => [
        1 => "White",
        2 => "Blue",
        3 => "Red",
        4 => "Yellow"
    ]
];


foreach($filters['brand'] as $key => $val){
    foreach($filters['color'] as $k => $v){
       echo "brand=$key,$val&color=$k,$v" . PHP_EOL;
       echo "brand=$val&color=$v" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output

```
brand=1,Adidas&color=1,White
brand=Adidas&color=White
...
```

Example 2;

```
foreach($filters['brand'] as $key => $val){
   echo "&brand=$key,$val&color=" . implode(',',$filters['color']) . PHP_EOL;
}

&brand=1,Adidas&color=White,Blue,Red,Yellow
&brand=2,Puma&color=White,Blue,Red,Yellow
```